# Rich Text Editor options

Tags: presentation

The out of the box Telerik RTE in Sitecore has been around a long time and served us well. But there are many options out there like Redactor. Has anyone implemented another more modern RTE in Sitecore?

Telerik is .NET so it has the ability to extract the HTML from the editor on save. Not sure the way forward on a JS only. Seems like I would have to write an API that the save event could post to.

Comment: The issue is some of the functionality within the RTE - _Link to Sitecore Items_ and _Insert from Media Library_. You'd need to replicate this functionality, and as others have stated, it's pretty hard baked in.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it asks for recommendations, which has been given and then abandoned by OP.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure you could easily just change the Rich Text editor controls with a different editor, but an option you could use would be to create a new custom field, you could call it "Rich Text (Editor Type)" and then when you are configuring the Custom Fields rendering, you could have it pull in a different editor instead of the default telerik editor.

Comment: That may be a great idea, Kind of how Mike West created a code editor. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JgOSdjgG_qs https://marketplace.sitecore.net/en/Modules/Code_Editor.aspx

Answer (score -2):

Sitecore RTE can not be replaced by another control . Sitecore is using Telerik controls by its foundation and it's not possible by just writing API or patching any code by Config file .

But it's possible to use same Telerik control with the numbers of customization.

To extend feature of rich text you need to make change default.aspx which can be found (/Sitecore/Shell/controls/Rich Text Editor/default.aspx)
For Example : 
This is the daualt entry for richtext control sitecore in default.aspx

You can add your extensions here by replacing or adding custom JS .