# Has anyone ever tried to replace an RTE in Sitecore, with something custom like tinyMCE? If there is there any instructions?

Tags: sitecore-client, richtext-editor

I would like to replace the default RTE in Sitecore with tinyMCE, how would I do it? Where do I start?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I went down this path in [this](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/2812/rich-text-editor-options) question. To this point I don't think anyone has pulled it off. And its mainly because there is so much Sitecore functionality in the RTE (i.e. Links, photos, etc...) Your best bet it to just allow the editors to have a custom HTML editor similar to what Michael West did. You can wire in your client side editor the same way Mike did.

See his module here http://marketplace.sitecore.net/en/Modules/Code_Editor.aspx

A great video on it here http://youtube.com/watch?v=JgOSdjgG_qs

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same question some time ago. The good starting point for me was taking [Emanuele Ciriachi module](https://emanueleciriachi.net/tinymce-sitecore-usage-configuration/) and extending it.

Then [I did](https://exdst.com/posts/sitecore-tiny-mce-new-life):

1. Unicorn serialization
2. Using `npm` for getting TinyMCE
3. Updating TinyMCE to the actual version
4. CI/CD setup
5. Sonar cloud configuration
6. Mix of Sitecore classic RTE and TinyMCE RTE
7. Sitecore 10 support
8. Switch to Nuget packages for referencing Sitecore assemblies
9. Improved development setup

Now the instruction on how to replace Sitecore RTE with TinyMCE is as simple as possible.

1. Open Update Installation Wizard
2. Install TinyMCE package
3. Change field types

Or if you need to use another editor, not TinyMCE, you can take [sources](https://github.com/antonytm/sitecore-tinymcerte) as a starting point and replace TinyMCE with RTE that you prefer.

Answer (score -1):

I'm supporting a Sitecore 6.5 site where TinyMCE has been used to replace the default rich text editor.

This article covers the setup https://sitecore.wordpress.com/2009/02/20/sitecore-forum-module-using-tinymce-instead-of-freetextbox/

Comment: Please update your answer to have more details on how you implemented your solution. As it stands now you have only provided a link and the link may or may not exist in the future which won't be helpful when someone comes to this question on how to replace the RTE.

Comment: The article also only covers replacing it in the forum module, which may not have been using the Telerik one the main CMS uses. Looking at the code, it's not enough to replace the main one.